# saving a modal box state with cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have created a pop up modal box for my html page using this tutorial:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

What I'd like to do now via cookies is remember whether the modal was displayed or hidden when the user left the page and after they return and the modal was displayed when the user left the page, it should show as displayed.

This is the script code for the modal popup:

```
    <script>

var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("logo");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}


span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

So when the user clicks on logo, the modal pops up and when the user clicks anywhere else, it disappears.

Now here I was trying to set up a cookie to remember the state of the modal and load it accordingly when the user returns to the page:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    var expiration = new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 8, 1)).toUTCString();

    var cookie = escape(popup) + "=" + escape(modal.style.display) + ";expires=" + expiration + ";";

    document.cookie = cookie;

    // read cookie

    var state = modal.style.display

    var key = modal.style.display + "=";

    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {

        var cookie = cookies[i];

        while (cookie.charAt(0) === ' ') {

            cookie = cookie.substring(1, cookie.length);
        }

            if (cookie.indexOf(key) === "block") {

                modal.style.display = "block";
            }

            else if (cookie.indexOf(key) === "none") {

                modal.style.display = "none";

            }
    }

});

</script>
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. Been searching the web for solution but couldn't find anything.

One more thing. In case javascript is disabled in the browser, I want the modal box to be permanently displayed. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) create separate functions that will control opening and closing your modal (so you can call them from multiple actions without rewriting the code -- easier to debug and maintain) (2) write the page without any JavaScript and have the modal auto-displayed this way.  So, if JS is disabled, the default state for the page is a displayed modal (3) W3C (and other online tools) should have good tutorials on setting/reading cookies where you can detect the value and then call your openModal() function if the cookie value is appropriate...

Comment: ... although, in your case, you really would be testing if the modal was already closed and then call a closeModal() function if the user previously closed it. (since the default behavior would be an exposed modal)

Comment: This W3C article may help https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp although there's tons more if you it's not your flavor.  And there's no shame in copy/pasting code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately (for good reason) this code will throw an error, because the snippet tool does not allow COOKIEs to be set.

Quick recap:

1) Created openModal() and closeModal() to control the modal window -- this way the code can exist in one place but be triggered by different conditions.  This makes it much easier to maintain, moving forward.

2) The styles for the modal window are set as though the modal is designed to be part of the page (without JavaScript).  So, when the page loads, regardless of JS, the modal will be present.

3) I copied W3C's COOKIE code (found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp ) for setting and getting COOKIE values.

4) Instead of downloading jQuery just for the $(document).ready() command, I created a documentLoad() function that will give you the same results.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById("logo");
// target the modal element for it's close button
var span = modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

function openModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'block';
  setCookie("modalDisplay", true, 365);
}
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none';
  setCookie("modalDisplay", false, 365);
}

// Events to listen for from the HTML
span.addEventListener('click', function(){
  closeModal();
});
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  openModal();
});
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
      closeModal();
  }
});

// COOKIE code copied from W3C
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function documentLoad(){
  modalDisplay = getCookie( 'modalDisplay' );
  // if the modal has already been closed...
  if( !modalDisplay ){
    closeModal();
  }
}
// instead of jQuery's document.ready() this code is 
// calling a function on its own
documentLoad();
```

```css
#myModal{
  display: block;
  padding: 35%;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.75 );
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="logo">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal">TEST MODAL <button class="close">X</button></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much but it doesnt seem to be working for me. I opened the modal, then went to another page (the modal was left open) but when I clicked back to return to my page the modal was closed.

Comment: Can you try stepping through each component of your code? (1) Try the page without any JavaScript? Does the modal still appear? (2) Try to open/close the modal? (3) Check if cookies are being saved (web dev toolbar) (4) Check if the JS is reading the cookies

Comment: with javascript disabled the modal does not appear

Comment: Ok, then re-write the CSS to show the modal without JS -- #myModal{ display: block; } -- and then from there you can advance to the next check, opening & closing :)

Comment: if I do display block it shows up as soon as I enter the page which isn' supposed to happen.

Comment: If you want the modal window to exist, regardless of JavaScript, but you want it to still fade in, then it may be good to try and use CSS transitions -- but that may screw up when you get to the JS phase.

Comment: Ok for now I'll be very glad if I can get the cookie to work. The cookie called modalDisplay is being saved. How do I check if js is reading it?

Comment: For brevity, working from Google Chrome: (1) confirm that the cookie is being set (web dev tools -> application -> cookies) ... check if the cookie exists with the expected value. (2) you can use the `getCookie('modalDisplay')` function (available above or on the W3C page) and alert what it returns

Comment: yes the cookie is being saved with the expected value. true if the modal is visible and false if it's hidden.

Comment: ok cool :) so where you call getCookie('modalDisplay'), it returns the value of the cookie -- so you can just do something like `var cookieVal = getCookie('modalDisplay'); alert( cookieVal );` (wherever you'd like, really)

Comment: why cant I just do something like modal.style.display =getCookie( 'modalDisplay' );  when the user enters the page? thats all I wanna do honestly :D

Comment: You can -- you'll just need to set the cookie value to "block" / "none" in respect to its state (instead of true v. false)

Comment: well I just did that and it still doesnt remember the modal was open when I left the page and returned :(

Comment: function documentLoad(){

        modalDisplay = getCookie( 'modalDisplay' );

        if (modalDisplay) {

            openModal(); 

        }

        else if (!modalDisplay) {

            closeModal();

        }

        } I did this but the modal opens even if the cookie value is set to false. I really dont know what Im doing wrong here

Comment: You should be good with just if(modalDisplay){ ... }else{ ... } Can you drop an alert or something similar before both function calls to make sure they're getting called as expected

Comment: Okay it almost works. I enter the page, click to display the modal. Then I leave the page (while modal is displayed) and when I come back I see it displayed just like I left it. Wonderful. One last problem however remains. If I F5 the page the modal displays immediately without me clicking on anything and I don't want that to happen. What should I do?

Comment: F5 should trigger similar actions to opening the page again. You can't really hack the browser.

Comment: so why does the box pop up when the cookie is false after F5?

Comment: what value does the cookie return after an F5 (via the JS, not web dev tools) ?

Comment: how do I do that again? sorry for the long discussion but I feel like we're almost there!

Comment: where you call getCookie('modalDisplay') , use an alert or console.log() to print out the returned value

Comment: it's false and the modal pops up anyways.

Comment: Can you copy what you have into jsFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: heres the script part, almost same as what you wrote above - https://jsfiddle.net/k3phyn7L/

Comment: drop in a new console/alert right before the openModal() and closeModal() on your documentLoad() function

Comment: just did, it says false

Comment: Add unique messages, pretty much all over the place :) like in openModal() : `console.log('openModal has been called...')` or in the documentLoad() : `console.log('cookie is false, calling closeModal()');`  this should help you map out what is being called and in what order.

Comment: okay i figured it out :) works now :) I did if (modalDisplay== true) instead of if (modalDisplay) and now when I press F5, the modal doesnt appear. Thanks very much for all your asistance :)